# 'tuple object is not callable'

Tags: python, tuples

```
import random
from random import *

stack = []

num = eval(input("How many words are there?"))

for x in range(num):
    w = input("What is the word?")
    d = input("Definiton of the word?")
    card = (w , d)
    stack.insert(0, card)
    print(card)

print(stack)

answer = input("What is the word that corresponds with ",    choice(stack[card]))
if answer == w:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

The 'answer = input("What is the word that corresponds with ",    choice(stack[card]))' line is not working, and is returning the error "tuple object is not callable." What do i change?

Comment: From the code sample, I'd guess `choice` is [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice)

Comment: Also, the error message I got when I tried to run this in python3 is `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple`. Which version of python is this, and why are you using `eval`?

Comment: eval makes the input an integer, and i am running this in 3.4

Comment: I really want to know who goes around telling people to use `eval(input())`, because it's never a good idea. In your case, use `int(input())`.

Answer (score 2):

The input function takes at most one argument. You are passing 2. Instead, use the string format method to format your prompt, then pass it to input. Also the call to choice should take the list of items to choose from, not a particular item in the list and card is a tuple, not an index. You need to go back and make sure you understand more about the fundamentals before you proceed.

```
(word, definition) = choice(stack)
prompt = 'What is the word that corresponds with "{}"'.format(defintion)
answer = input(prompt)
if answer == word:
    print("Correct!")
else:
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: This still doesn't work; `card` is a tuple, so you're indexing a list with a tuple.

Comment: Ah.. thought it was a dict. Fixed my example.